# Javascript: Global object alteration working in debugger but not in real use-case

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, object, scope

I'm having a bit of a struggle right now as to what the heck I'm doing wrong: 
I have established a global JavaScript object with another object inside like this:

```
rState = {
...
currentState: {}
...
};
```

There usually are some other properties in `currentState` like

```
currentState = {
    r-0: 'Name',
    r-1: 'Name2'
}
```

Those are represented in HTML as fancy chips with a **delete** button on the side. There's an event handler bound to each one of those buttons to remove the element from the DOM **AND** from the global object `rState` as well, just like this:

```
var events = {
  removeName: function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if(window.rState.currentState.hasOwnProperty(id)){
        window.rState.currentState[id] = "";
    }
    if(window.rState.initialState.hasOwnProperty(id)){
        window.rState.initialState[id] = "";
    }
    console.log(window.rState.currentState);
    $(this).parent().detach();
  },
  ...
};
```

There definitely is no other magic happening to those names in the rest of the code. This function simply overrides the corresponding property to the chip's id with an empty string.

When clicked, the chip correctly invokes the event handler, the property in `currentState` gets adresses and overwritten *when things are inspected with a debugger* (Chrome Dev Tools)

**ACTUALLY** When inspected step by step with the debugger it all works properly, the global object property gets overwritten and, which is where things get interesting, **stays that way**.

Now here comes my problem:

When executed without that debugger, things start to go mad. 
Let's assume we have a `currentState` like that:

```
currentState = {'r-0': 'Name1', 'r-1': 'Name2', 'r-2': 'Name3'}
```

Clicking on that remove button of the chip with the id `r-0` first of all invokes the **correct** event handler. With the `console.log` in the code, I receive an output like that

```
currentState = {'r-0': '', 'r-1': 'Name2', 'r-2': 'Name3'}
```

which seems to be correct.
Using the Dev Tools then to inspect the global `rState` object's currentState, which theoretically should be altered due to its global scope gives me

```
currentState = {'r-0': 'Name1', 'r-1': 'Name2', 'r-2': 'Name3'}
```

like the object was never touched by anything.
Then clicking on the chip with the id 'r-1' gives me, as now, as you know there's a problem with the code (*or whatever it is*), to expect

```
currentState = {'r-0': 'Name1', 'r-1': '', 'r-2': 'Name3'}
```

and actually not altering that `rState.currentState` at all as well, which leaves me totally scattered in front of my code since hours.

I've done excessive googling and searching through post of others having issues with scope and altering objects like this but none of those solutions seem to work. I'm quite lost right now.